# Does SNI really require TLSv1 (insecure)?

Tags: redirect, apache-2.4, sni

From the Apache 2.4 [docs](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI):

> The first (default) vhost for SSL name-based virtual hosts must include TLSv1 as a permitted protocol, otherwise Apache will not accept the SNI information from the client and it will be as if the client did not support SNI at all.

I want to have multiple TLS enabled sites on my server, each giving a different certificate. For security reasons, I only allow TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2. Is there a secure way to turn on SNI?

A snippet from my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
    [other SSL options]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.org/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
    [other SSL options]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I suspect that's an error. Does the configuration work?

Comment: encountered  the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

The wiki is contrasting TLSv1 from earlier protocols, not later protocols.  SNI works fine with TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

Comment: So you mean it should read "TLSv1 OR LATER" indicating a TLS level must be present.

Comment: In a sense yes. It just requires TLS extensions which are TLS1.0 and later only.  TLSv1 is ambiguous, but in a doc that talks about an openssl .9.8 prerequisite take it with grain of salt.

(Tried to edit the wiki, but it's notoriously slow.)